# Redirecting DNS without breaking everything

Tags: redirect, dns

I have a wordpress installation at a location in the form: www.mydomain.com/mysite.

I would like to redirect the DNS such that the address will (always!) appear as mysite.com.

I own both domain names. How can I do the redirection without breaking everything?

Comment: Two steps, but I dont think you did #1 yet: 1) Your WP site needs to be configured to run as mysite.com, 2) You can either add redirect in DNS or you can add redirection rules in .htaccess

Comment: @user42826 By 1) do you mean changing the site name in the general setting? And by 2) do you mean adding a DNS redirection directly?

Answer (score 1):

1) You have to change all references of www.mydomain.com to mysite.com in WP. WP will only respond to the hostname/url that it was configured for.  If you make a request with a different url, WP will respond with an error message.  WP stores the url in two places wp-config.php and the database.  In wp-config.php just do a manual search and replace.  For the database one method to change site's url - export the database, do a search and replace, then import (be sure to keep a copy of the original export as backup).  There are also plugin that will do the search and replace for you.

2) DNS change.  This depends on your DNS provider of www.mydomain.com.  Some providers have the ability to add 301 redirects.  See if your DNS provider has this capability.  If not, you can add 301 redirects into your WP .htaccess near the top

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Here is an plugin that will do a search and replace of urls (I didnt want to include in my answer) - https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/

Comment: Sorry, I'm really bad at this. What should I put in the .htaccess file exactly, using the names from my example? And where should I put them, below the line that says "<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>" ? Thank you...

Comment: Yes put it after that IfModule directive.

Answer (score 0):

> The easiest way to move a WordPress website from one domain to another is to create a mysql database dump and import this data into the new website.

Backup your site files and database. Export the database, drop all the tables in said database, then use this tool to change the URL from old to new here - http://pixelentity.com/wordpress-search-replace-domain/

> this online tool to solve this problem by letting you replace an old domain or URL with a new one while fixing the serialized data at the same time.

We serialize the data because there are character counts for everything and since www. or /site has more characters than the .com as we want it will cause problems.

Once you have the fresh and clean database from that website, import it.

Move all your files from the /mysite directory to the public root folder.

Now put this in your .htaccess to redirect all www to non-www

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]`

DONE AND DONE :)

Comment: Thanks. But I don't really want to change the domain, only redirect the DNS calls...

Comment: This isn't only for the domain name. It works for all URLs

Comment: "You have to change all references of www.mydomain.com to mysite.com in WP." That is what I am referring to. What you are asking really has nothing to do with DNS as you've already got it propagating from what it reads like

Comment: I don't know. I have changed all the entries in the database. The problem is that I get a "DNS lookup failed" as I try to load the page.

Comment: I see. What do you have your DNS setup like? Does the domain name simply have nameservers assigned? Or are there unique records at the registrar? If the nameservers are assigned have you modified the DNS cluster on the host?

Comment: I am a real noob here, no idea. If I tell my host to redirect the DNS, I can see the page appearing, but all the internal links are broken, including wp-admin.

Comment: If you're not sure you can use this tool to take a look digwebinterface.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48527/discussion-between-jarmerson-and-geodude).